# Knockout.js CSS Computed From Observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two observables, one that specifies a module name and the other that sets a height for some of its children. I am trying to make a custom css computed observable that includes these two observables like so:

```
self.moduleId = ko.observable('dbm-name');
self.slideWidth = ko.observable(75);
self.css = ko.observable('');
self.setcss = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return '#' + self.moduleId() +
               ' {\n\tbackground: #fff;\n\tcolor: #000;\n}
                  \n.cont_width {\n\twidth: ' + self.slideWidth() +
               '%;\n}';
    },
    write: function(value) {
        self.css(value);
        return value;
    }
});
```

but it should also allow the user to manually write/edit some css. The problem is that once either `moduleId` or `slideWidth` is changed the css observable is not updated unless the user goes into the custom css textarea and makes a change (ie. add and remove a space just to get it to update). How can I automatically update the css observable when either of the other two observable values change? Or is there a better way of setting up my css functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the read function to also set your css:

```
self.setcss = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var _css = '#' + self.moduleId() +
                '{\n\tbackground: #fff;\n\tcolor: #000;\n}' +
                '\n.cont_width {\n\twidth: ' + self.slideWidth() +
                '%;\n}';
            self.css(_css);       
        },
        write: self.css
 });
```

But like this you can only have one of the values as your css, either the user typed css or the computed product, at each moment in time.

But I suppose you could modify the read in such a way that it either concatenating the values to add the new one at the end of the css you already have.

[here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJV3L/29/)